# Adding bound checks to WinForms with multiple screens

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application that asks the user questions and allows them to advance to the next question by clicking "Next" and going back to the previous question by pressing "Previous."

I currently have the controls set up to read questions from an XML (so the number of questions is dynamic, not hard-coded) and have 10 questions this time around.

Here is my code:

```
private void DisplayQuestion(int questionNumber)
{
  var qNumber = _xmlHandler.Questions[questionNumber];
  if (string.Equals(qNumber.QuestionType, "ComboBoxControl"))
  {
    controlPanel.Controls.Clear();
    var comboBox = new ComboBoxControl();
    comboBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    controlPanel.Controls.Add(comboBox);
  }

}

private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DisplayQuestion(++_questionNumber);
}

private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DisplayQuestion(--_questionNumber);
}
```

This works for me now but, as expected, I get an exception error when I hit "previous" on the first screen and hit "next" on the last (10th) screen.  How can I add bounds to the above code to allow the user to potentially go back and forth several times but also make sure that they don't go below 0 or over 10?

I've tried using a basic for loop but I've found that even with the loop I wrote, when "next" is hit 10 times it will end - even if you've also hit "previous" several times and may only be on question #5 because you jumped through them and back again.

Comment: Simply check the value of *questionNumber*.  And disable the Back button when it reaches zero.  There's a very serious bug in your code, Controls.Clear() will leak window handles badly.  You *must* call the Dispose() method on controls you remove.

Comment: Could you provide an example of disabling the back button when it reaches zero?  That's a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your events can access `_xmlHandler.Questions`, check the value of `_questionNumber` against the number of elements in your collection before changing it. This way, you don't have to change the number when you add or remove questions in the future.

```
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (_questionNumber < _xmlHandler.Questions.Count - 1)
    DisplayQuestion(++_questionNumber);
}

private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (_questionNumber > 0)
    DisplayQuestion(--_questionNumber);
}
```

Comment: When I used this, it let me click Next and Previous endlessly and I was able to click previous and next 20 times each in a row and I never hit my bounds.

Comment: Well right now there are no questions populating the form.  I wanted to get the form control down before I did this.  But essentially without your code I am able to hit "back" and get an exception, and am able to click "next" 10 times and get another exception because I've gone below 0 and above 10 respectively.  With your code, I can click "back" and "next" endlessly and continue to go below 0 and above 10.  I need to get it to where I can't go below 0 and above x [which is currently 10, but ultimately that'll be how many <Question>s I have in my XML.

Comment: Good call.  I will look into this.  Thanks.

Comment: This was the closest thing to what I was looking for, thanks again Grant!

Answer (score 1):

```
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_questionNumber == 10)
        return;
    DisplayQuestion(++_questionNumber);
}

private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_questionNumber == 1)
        return;
    DisplayQuestion(--_questionNumber);
}
```

Comment: That's a good hard-coded approach but the end-goal of the project is to have a reusable survey program that only needs a new XML file to function.

So not every XML will have 10 questions, it may be 5, it may be 20, it's all going to depend on the XML.